# If $N$ is normal, $W^\ast(N)=\{N\}''$

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

I want to prove that if $N$ is normal, then $W^\ast(N)=\{N\}''$, where $W^\ast(N)$ is the Von Neumann algebra generated by $N$ and $\{N\}''$ is the bicommutant of $N$.

for the inclusion $W^\ast(N) \subseteq\{N\}''$:
is simple to see that $\{N\}''$ is an abelian $*$-algebra WOT closed containing 1 and $N$, i.e. a Von Neumann algebra.

I'm blocked for the second inclusion.
It's likely I have to use the bicommutant theorem.
Can you give me a hand please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the spectral theorem, $C^*(I, N)$ is a commutative C*-algebra. We have $W^*(N) = W^*(C^*(N,I))$. By the bicommutant theorem,

$$W^*(C^*(N,I)) = C^*(N,I)^{\prime \prime} = \{N\}^{\prime \prime}.$$

Comment: I have two questions: why by the spectral theorem? Isn't trivial that $C^\ast(1,N)$ is commutative for N normal? Second question. In the last equality is clear that $C^\ast(N,I)''\subseteq \{N\}''$ but why there is an equality?

Comment: Good the other inclusion comes from the Fulgede-Putnam theorem: with this you can say that $\{N\}'  C^\ast(N,I)'$ and then $C^\ast(N,I)''\subseteq \{N\}''$